# Calculating floating point error bound

Tags: c#, floating-point, geometry

I have geometrical algorithms and im struggling with floating point inaccuracies.
For example, I'm calculating wether a point lies on the left/right/on a plane (C#):

```
    const double Epsilon = 1e-10;
    internal double ComputeDistance(Vector3D v)
    {
        Vector3D normal = Plane.Normal;
        Vertex v0 = Plane.Origin;
        double a = normal.X;
        double b = normal.Y;
        double c = normal.Z;
        double d = -(a * v0.X + b * v0.Y + c * v0.Z);

        return a * v.X + b * v.Y + c * v.Z + d;
    }

    internal string DistanceSign(Vector3D v)
    {
        var distance = ComputeDistance(v);
        return (distance > Epsilon ? "left" : (distance < -Epsilon ? "right" : "on"));
    }
```

As shown in the code, I use a fixed Epsilon value.

But I don't trust this fixed epsilon because I don't know the size of the floating point error. If the fp error is bigger than my epsilon interval, then my algorithm will fail.
How can I make it robust? I have searched on the internet but haven't found a solution so far. I have read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic", it describes why fp errors occur but not how to solve them practically.

**Edit**

Here is a shewchuk predicate that doesn't seem work:

```
        double[] pa = {0, 0};
        double[] pb = {2 * Double.Epsilon, 0};
        double[] pc = { 0, Double.Epsilon };

        Assert.IsTrue(GeometricPredicates.Orient2D(pa, pb, pc) > 0);
```

The assertion fails because Orient2D return 0. The code is [here](https://github.com/govert/RobustGeometry.NET/blob/master/RobustGeometry/Predicates/GeometricPredicates.cs)

**Edit2**

Shouldn't it be possible to calculate an error bound by using the machine epsilon? According to wikipedia, the machine epsilon is an upper bound due to rounding. For double, it is 2^−53. So as I take it, when I have an arithmetic calculation:
    double x = y + z
then the maximum error should be 2^−53. Shouldn't this fact enable the possiblity to calculate an appropriate epsilon? So two rewrite my method:

```
    double const Machine_Eps = 1.11022302462516E-16 // (2^-53)
    double Epsilon = Machine_Eps; 
    internal double ComputeDistance(Vector3D v)
    {
        Vector3D normal = Plane.Normal;
        Vertex v0 = Plane.Origin;
        double a = normal.X;
        double b = normal.Y;
        double c = normal.Z;

        // 3 multiplications + 2 additions = maximum of 5*Machine_Eps
        double d = -(a * v0.X + b * v0.Y + c * v0.Z);

        // 3 multiplications + 3 additions = maximum of 6*Machine_Eps
        Epsilon = 11 * Machine_Eps;
        return a * v.X + b * v.Y + c * v.Z + d;
    }

    internal string DistanceSign(Vector3D v)
    {
        var distance = ComputeDistance(v);
        return (distance > Epsilon ? "left" : (distance < -Epsilon ? "right" : "on"));
    }
```

Ok now you can tell me how wrong I am. :)

Comment: Creating robust geometric predicates is very hard. You might want to check out [Jonathan Shewchuk's work](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html) on this topic.

Comment: I'm aware of Shewchuk's predicates, I have even tried [this](https://github.com/govert/RobustGeometry.NET/wiki/Floating-point-on-.NET) .Net implementation but the predicates have failed when using very small numbers.

Comment: As far as I am aware, Shewchuk's approach requires strict adherance to IEEE-754 semantics, including denormal support. In the C/C++ world many compilers do not guarantee this *unless* specific compiler switches are given, such as: `/fp:strict`. I do not know .Net, but it is probably worth examining whether this could be an issue. Any implementation of Shewchuk's primitives could also suffer from plain old programming bugs, so worth double checking from that side as well.

Comment: @NMO: On what platform and with what specific numbers?

Comment: @tmyklebu I'll post an example

Comment: Platform is Windows 10 64bit and .Net 4.5.

Comment: Gotcha.  `Double.Epsilon` on .NET is, I recall, the smallest normal `double` rather than machine epsilon.  I haven't got a good workaround for you besides ensuring that you have a less badly-scaled problem than that.

Comment: I have googled machine epsilon. Shouldn't it be possible to calculate an error bound using the machine epsilon? According to Wikipedia: "or a number system and a rounding procedure, machine epsilon is the maximum relative error of the chosen rounding procedure.". So for example, when looking at my ComputeDistance method, more precisely at this expression: "double d = -(a * v0.X + b * v0.Y + c * v0.Z);", I could calculate an error bound: Three multiplications + two additions should result in a maximum error of 5*machine epsilon for this expression, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'll post some code to make it clear what I mean.

Comment: The only corner case to your example is when the point is very close to the plane - normalizer the coordinates and after scale them? Or I am missing something?